# systemd can't mount partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, systemd

I use a ssh tunnel at work to browse the internet.
Yesterday I realize that my terminal is very slow responding to commands, I inspect htop, iotop, netop and see nothing in particular, only the console is slow, the tunnel works fine.

Coming back home I try to log in my X session, and the computer hangs for 5min after I press the Enter key.

I decide to reboot, and end up in systemd emergency mode.

Looking at the journalctl (here [pastebined](http://pastebin.com/raw/FUCPZWnm)) I try a few things, among them commenting some partition / devices in my /etc/fstab.

It happens that when I comment my /home I can log in normally. Here is my /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=f0e6eea4-264d-42f2-97c1-0ad6d60e9e76 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=d464c414-6e10-4fb1-adaf-43096cf52ab5 none            swap    sw              0       0
# changed home on new partition
#UUID=83192ee9-fd8a-4d8c-9988-bca2d0fdf630   /home   ext4   nodev,nosuid   0   2
#/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
#/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
#/dev/md0   /media/raid5   ext4   defaults   0   0

#UUID=ea59484a-3652-4d1d-a398-f417cbd0ae7c   /media/backup   ext4   defaults   0   0

# for virtualbox, changed on june 5th
#none   /proc/bus/usb   usbfs   devgid=126,devmode=664   0   0

# for sftp in chroot
#/media/raid5/TV\040SHOWS/   /home/quest/tv/      ext4   bind,ro      0   0
#/media/raid5/MOVIES/      /home/quest/movies/   ext4   bind,ro      0   0
#/media/raid5/ANIME/      /home/quest/anime/   ext4   bind,ro      0   0

#garmin fenix 2
#UUID=489A-9E97         /media/raid5/fenix2   vfat   defaults,user,noauto,errors=remount-ro   0   1
```

So I try to understand a little better what can happen and decide to see if there is a mismatch in uuid (I saw a few posts talking about that), but unfortunately the uuid do match. See blkid output:

```
/dev/sdc1: UUID="e7c87d29-37d0-d6b4-9a33-6d4f0e239a13" UUID_SUB="4cc4d747-5c88-9bc6-59c1-5f29603fba57" LABEL="bigbenn:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="Linux filesystem" PARTUUID="af78f725-7354-448b-a3f7-9149937d440c"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="83192ee9-fd8a-4d8c-9988-bca2d0fdf630" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8aaed40e-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="f0e6eea4-264d-42f2-97c1-0ad6d60e9e76" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8aaed40e-05"
/dev/sdb6: UUID="d464c414-6e10-4fb1-adaf-43096cf52ab5" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="8aaed40e-06"
/dev/sde1: UUID="ea59484a-3652-4d1d-a398-f417cbd0ae7c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1433120b-01"
/dev/sdf1: UUID="e7c87d29-37d0-d6b4-9a33-6d4f0e239a13" UUID_SUB="69383fe0-2113-a305-87fe-51057bfdd681" LABEL="bigbenn:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="873db73f-01"
/dev/sda1: UUID="e7c87d29-37d0-d6b4-9a33-6d4f0e239a13" UUID_SUB="cfdfaca9-f350-3c3a-a6a7-75a9844e9660" LABEL="bigbenn:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="4483559b-01"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="e7c87d29-37d0-d6b4-9a33-6d4f0e239a13" UUID_SUB="efb1db76-0169-ee95-ba36-d64adf36de65" LABEL="bigbenn:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="092c2257-01"
/dev/sdg1: UUID="e7c87d29-37d0-d6b4-9a33-6d4f0e239a13" UUID_SUB="c6dc6576-3d94-e0e9-77b8-abb62563277d" LABEL="bigbenn:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="000d77f7-01"
/dev/md0: UUID="0a0dc09a-0714-4fed-99e2-31a08b753373" TYPE="ext4"
```

Now I'm at a loss, I tried also to smartctl the disk where my /home is, and it seems normal (test passed) but I'm not sure as there are errors at the end... [here is the smartctl](http://pastebin.com/raw/hpBnhEvn)

Comment: Pastebin is not the right tool for amending Stack Exchange questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a strange situation, whereby udev does not seem to start mounting partitions until systemd has completed, but this runs into problems when such partitions are mentioned in /etc/fstab: in that case udev waits for systemd to complete (and this leads to a time out), and only **then** it mounts the partition.

I have no idea whatsoever about how this may have come about. I know though that you can solve your problem by creating a new service: create a file */etc/systemd/system/mounthome.service* into which you place this code:

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Mount Home
 DefaultDependencies=no

 [Service]
 Type=oneshot
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 ExecStart=/bin/mount /dev/sdb1
```

and now add to the file */usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udev-trigger.service* the following line,

```
 Wants=systemd-udevd.service mounthome.service
```

so that it looks as follows:

```
  [Unit]
  Description=udev Coldplug all Devices
  Documentation=man:udev(7) man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
  DefaultDependencies=no
  Wants=systemd-udevd.service mounthome.service
  After=systemd-udevd-kernel.socket systemd-udevd-control.socket
  Before=sysinit.target
  ConditionCapability=CAP_MKNOD

  [Service]
  Type=oneshot
  RemainAfterExit=yes
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/udevadm trigger --type=subsystems --action=add ; /usr/bin/udevadm trigger
```

I believe this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

nodev stands for "do not interpret block special devices on the filesystem"
Try changing the arguments from nodev and nosuid to "defaults"
If that won't work, try change the mounting point of your drive to something different than home, let's say create directory home2, and mount it there, then issue: "sudo ln -s /home2 /home". 
Hope it helps