# systemd - restricted access to mounted volumes?

Tags: linux, debian, mount, systemd

After debian system upgrade one of my services (mpd - music player daemon) stopped working - saying that it cannot access the folder with the music. Trying to troubleshoot I noticed two things:

1. The problem only exists when I run the mpd as a systemd service - when run directly, it works fine
2. The problem only exists when the music directory is on a mounted volume (rather than in root volume)

So it seems that systemd somehow restricts access to mounted devices. I have no idea why.

Minimal test case:

1) set up new volume

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/dummy.img bs=1M count=50
# mkfs.ext4 /root/dummy.img
# mkdir /mnt/dummy
# mount /root/dummy.img /mnt/dummy
# mkdir /mnt/dummy/music
# chmod a+rwx /mnt/dummy/ -R
```

2) modify /etc/mpd.conf

```
music_directory "/mnt/dummy/music"
```

3) start mpd

```
# service mpd start
# service mpd status
```

Then in mpd log I get:

```
Jan 18 20:20:27 seal mpd[7948]: Jan 18 20:20 : exception: Failed to access /mnt/dummy/music: No such file or directory
```

Please note that if I run the mpd directly:

```
# mpd --stdout --no-daemon --verbose
```

there is no such error.

Also if I use any folder on the root volume, even /root/music, which is only readable for the root user, it also works fine (for the troubleshooting purposes I run mpd as root).

It is only the combination of systemd + mounted volume that doesn't work.

Systemd service config attached:

```
# systemctl show mpd
Type=notify
Restart=no
NotifyAccess=main
RestartUSec=100ms
TimeoutStartUSec=1min 30s
TimeoutStopUSec=1min 30s
RuntimeMaxUSec=infinity
WatchdogUSec=0
WatchdogTimestamp=Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:40 CET
WatchdogTimestampMonotonic=19176253623
PermissionsStartOnly=no
RootDirectoryStartOnly=no
RemainAfterExit=no
GuessMainPID=yes
MainPID=8154
ControlPID=0
FileDescriptorStoreMax=0
NFileDescriptorStore=0
StatusErrno=0
Result=success
UID=[not set]
GID=[not set]
NRestarts=0
ExecMainStartTimestamp=Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:39 CET
ExecMainStartTimestampMonotonic=19175700632
ExecMainExitTimestampMonotonic=0
ExecMainPID=8154
ExecMainCode=0
ExecMainStatus=0
ExecStart={ path=/usr/bin/mpd ; argv[]=/usr/bin/mpd --no-daemon $MPDCONF ; ignore_errors=no ; start_time=[Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:39 CET] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=8154 ; code=(null) ; status=0/0 }
Slice=system.slice
ControlGroup=/system.slice/mpd.service
MemoryCurrent=[not set]
CPUUsageNSec=[not set]
TasksCurrent=5
IPIngressBytes=18446744073709551615
IPIngressPackets=18446744073709551615
IPEgressBytes=18446744073709551615
IPEgressPackets=18446744073709551615
Delegate=no
CPUAccounting=no
CPUWeight=[not set]
StartupCPUWeight=[not set]
CPUShares=[not set]
StartupCPUShares=[not set]
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
IOAccounting=no
IOWeight=[not set]
StartupIOWeight=[not set]
BlockIOAccounting=no
BlockIOWeight=[not set]
StartupBlockIOWeight=[not set]
MemoryAccounting=no
MemoryLow=0
MemoryHigh=infinity
MemoryMax=infinity
MemorySwapMax=infinity
MemoryLimit=infinity
DevicePolicy=auto
TasksAccounting=yes
TasksMax=4915
IPAccounting=no
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/mpd (ignore_errors=no)
UMask=0022
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitCPUSoft=infinity
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitFSIZESoft=infinity
LimitDATA=infinity
LimitDATASoft=infinity
LimitSTACK=infinity
LimitSTACKSoft=8388608
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitCORESoft=0
LimitRSS=infinity
LimitRSSSoft=infinity
LimitNOFILE=4096
LimitNOFILESoft=1024
LimitAS=infinity
LimitASSoft=infinity
LimitNPROC=15298
LimitNPROCSoft=15298
LimitMEMLOCK=16777216
LimitMEMLOCKSoft=16777216
LimitLOCKS=infinity
LimitLOCKSSoft=infinity
LimitSIGPENDING=15298
LimitSIGPENDINGSoft=15298
LimitMSGQUEUE=819200
LimitMSGQUEUESoft=819200
LimitNICE=0
LimitNICESoft=0
LimitRTPRIO=50
LimitRTPRIOSoft=50
LimitRTTIME=infinity
LimitRTTIMESoft=infinity
OOMScoreAdjust=0
Nice=0
IOSchedulingClass=0
IOSchedulingPriority=0
CPUSchedulingPolicy=0
CPUSchedulingPriority=0
TimerSlackNSec=50000
CPUSchedulingResetOnFork=no
NonBlocking=no
StandardInput=null
StandardInputData=
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
TTYReset=no
TTYVHangup=no
TTYVTDisallocate=no
SyslogPriority=30
SyslogLevelPrefix=yes
SyslogLevel=6
SyslogFacility=3
LogLevelMax=-1
SecureBits=0
CapabilityBoundingSet=cap_chown cap_dac_override cap_dac_read_search cap_fowner cap_fsetid cap_kill cap_setgid cap_setuid cap_setpcap cap_linux_immutable cap_net_bind_service cap_net_broadcast cap_net_admin cap_net_raw cap_ipc_lock cap_ipc_owner cap_sys_module cap_sys_rawio cap_sys_chroot cap_sys_ptrace cap_sys_pacct cap_sys_admin cap_sys_boot cap_sys_nice cap_sys_resource cap_sys_time cap_sys_tty_config cap_mknod cap_lease cap_audit_write cap_audit_control cap_setfcap cap_mac_override cap_mac_admin cap_syslog cap_wake_alarm cap_block_suspend
AmbientCapabilities=
DynamicUser=no
RemoveIPC=no
MountFlags=
PrivateTmp=no
PrivateDevices=no
ProtectKernelTunables=no
ProtectKernelModules=no
ProtectControlGroups=no
PrivateNetwork=no
PrivateUsers=no
ProtectHome=no
ProtectSystem=no
SameProcessGroup=no
UtmpMode=init
IgnoreSIGPIPE=yes
NoNewPrivileges=no
SystemCallErrorNumber=0
LockPersonality=no
RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=no
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
StateDirectoryMode=0755
CacheDirectoryMode=0755
LogsDirectoryMode=0755
ConfigurationDirectoryMode=0755
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=no
RestrictRealtime=no
RestrictNamespaces=no
MountAPIVFS=no
KeyringMode=private
KillMode=control-group
KillSignal=15
SendSIGKILL=yes
SendSIGHUP=no
Id=mpd.service
Names=mpd.service
Requires=system.slice sysinit.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Before=multi-user.target shutdown.target
After=sysinit.target basic.target sound.target mpd.socket network.target system.slice systemd-journald.socket
TriggeredBy=mpd.socket
Documentation=man:mpd(1) man:mpd.conf(5) file:///usr/share/doc/mpd/user-manual.html
Description=Music Player Daemon
LoadState=loaded
ActiveState=active
SubState=running
FragmentPath=/lib/systemd/system/mpd.service
DropInPaths=/etc/systemd/system/mpd.service.d/override.conf
UnitFileState=enabled
UnitFilePreset=enabled
StateChangeTimestamp=Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:40 CET
StateChangeTimestampMonotonic=19176253627
InactiveExitTimestamp=Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:39 CET
InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic=19175700719
ActiveEnterTimestamp=Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:40 CET
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=19176253627
ActiveExitTimestamp=Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:39 CET
ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic=19175684629
InactiveEnterTimestamp=Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:39 CET
InactiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=19175697364
CanStart=yes
CanStop=yes
CanReload=no
CanIsolate=no
StopWhenUnneeded=no
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no
AllowIsolate=no
DefaultDependencies=yes
OnFailureJobMode=replace
IgnoreOnIsolate=no
NeedDaemonReload=no
JobTimeoutUSec=infinity
JobRunningTimeoutUSec=infinity
JobTimeoutAction=none
ConditionResult=yes
AssertResult=yes
ConditionTimestamp=Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:39 CET
ConditionTimestampMonotonic=19175699119
AssertTimestamp=Thu 2018-01-18 20:24:39 CET
AssertTimestampMonotonic=19175699120
Transient=no
Perpetual=no
StartLimitIntervalSec=10000000
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitAction=none
FailureAction=none
SuccessAction=none
InvocationID=cb674c5c75a741dd8510acc8bbcc868b
CollectMode=inactive
```

I have no idea how to proceed. Will be glad for any hint.

Comment: I have a vague suspicion it's a namespaces bug that will be fixed in the next package release.

Comment: Thanks. I actually upgraded mpd a while ago again but nothing changed - same problem in two versions. Is it possible to fix it myself? What shall I look for? (I am not familiar with the namespaces)

Comment: @grawity I can confirm that if I compare /proc/PID/mounts of the mpd started directly and via systemd, the directly started contains the mounts while the systemd started does not. Any idea how can that be fixed?

Comment: I also noticed in lsns that sshd has its own mnt namespace. And I am connected to the machine via ssh and therefore probably mounting the volume in the sshd namespace invisible to the systemd. How can this mess be fixed?

Comment: similar question / [answer](https://superuser.com/a/850951/258947).

Comment: Fixed with sshd upgrade, systemd upgrade, and system reboot. After the reboot sshd no longer has a separate namespace and everything works as expected. Thank you for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a namespace issue. The volumes were mounted via ssh and sshd had its own mnt namespace (visible in lsns), so the mounts were not propagated to systemd started services.

Separate mnt namespace for sshd was probably a Debian/systemd bug. After sshd upgrade, systemd upgrade, and system restart the problem vanished.

Thanks @grawity for the tip in the commment.